# If, elseif and else not working like expected

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I'm trying to check with if and elseif multiply $_sessions if they exist and if they have a fixed value. 
My only problem is that the sessions all are in place and set to the expected value but my script doesn't go further then the second check.

So my question is here do i format the if, elseif, else not correctly or is it the way i check the session value's ? And what should i do at a other way?

Script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/cpbCZJ0k 
It's 145 lines so i'm really not going to post here since it is so long and would take up the whole page.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: do a print_r($_SESSION) on top of the page and what do you see? also move your session_start to the top of the page.

Comment: All sessions are set and yes session is started correctly, or else it woudnt do the first 2 checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression from your second if `isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 2 && isset($_SESSION['pre']) && $_SESSION['pre'] == 1` is also used in third one, so there are only two possibilities: script will execute second `if` or it'll just skip to `else` (because that expression returned `false` and third `if` will also fail).

You have to reverse second and third `if`s.

Comment: So i changed the Condition check to: if cookie = 1 elseif  cookie = 2 etc etc and updated my other scripts, much simpler and works :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 1 ){
...
elseif (isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 2 &&
       isset($_SESSION['pre']) && $_SESSION['pre'] == 1  ) {
...
elseif (isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 2 &&
       isset($_SESSION['pre']) && $_SESSION['pre'] == 1 &&
       isset($_SESSION['gedaan1']) && $_SESSION['gedaan1'] == 1 ) {
...
elseif (isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 2 &&
       isset($_SESSION['pre']) && $_SESSION['pre'] == 1 && 
       isset($_SESSION['gedaan1']) && $_SESSION['gedaan1'] == 1 && 
       isset($_SESSION['gedaan2']) && $_SESSION['gedaan2'] == 1) {
...
```

Now, notice that the first and second if clauses are incompatible, i.e. if the first is true the second will never be true and vise versa. That is a good case, your execution checks if the first clause is true, if it's true, the first branch is followed. If it's not true, the second clause is checked. If it's true, the second branch is followed.

Note that if the first clause is true, the second one *is not checked*. So for the case of third and fourth branches, if the first or second were true, no other branches will be followed, regardless of their `if` clauses.

However if the clause of the third/fourth branch is true, so is the clause of the second branch. Thus the execution can never reach the third or fourth branch, always ending up in the second (or first) branch.

Remembering the note about incompatible clauses, you may want to make clauses incompatible, say, make the 2nd branch look like

```
elseif (isset($_SESSION['gedaanx']) && $_SESSION['gedaanx'] == 2 &&
       isset($_SESSION['pre']) && $_SESSION['pre'] == 1 &&
       !isset($_SESSION['gedaan1'])  ) {
...
```

Or simply exchange the 4th branch and 2nd branch so that 4th is 2nd, 3rd is 3rd and 2nd is 4th. Then the 4th branch will be checked immediately after the 1st.

Comment: So i changed the Condition check to: if cookie = 1 elseif  cookie = 2 etc etc and updated my other scripts, much simpler and works :)